# Micronaut: Loggers not appearing in AWS Cloudwatch & Java application not running in local

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, micronaut, graalvm, graalvm-native-image, micronaut-aws

I have a `Micronaut` microservice which had to be upgraded with the following version changes:

1. `Micronaut bom` version: `1.3.1` to `1.3.4`
2. `Gradle`: `5.1.1` to `5.3`
3. `Graal VM`:`19.2.1`

I am building the native-image using the `buildspec.yml` as given below:

```
phases:
  build:
    commands:
      - 'mkdir -p build'
      - 'pwd'
      - 'ls'
      - 'chmod +x build-native-image.sh'
      - './build-native-image.sh'
      - 'cp /usr/lib/graalvm/jre/lib/amd64/libsunec.so libsunec.so'
      - 'chmod 755 bootstrap'
      - 'chmod 755 server'   
      - 'chmod 755 cacerts'   
      - 'chmod 755 libsunec.so'
      - 'BUILD_ID=$(cat build_id.txt)'
      - 'zip -j example-function-$BUILD_ID.zip bootstrap server cacerts libsunec.so build_id.txt'
artifacts:
  files:
     - './example-function-*.zip'
```

The `example-function.zip` got deployed to `AWS Lambda`and while testing it through `APIGateway`, I am able to get the response but unable to view the loggers that I used in my service in the `CloudWatch Logs`.

I have followed this article https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisanalytics/latest/java/cloudwatch-logs-writing.html#cloudwatch-logs-writing-slf4j for adding the Logger dependency to my `build.gradle` file but the logs are still not showing up on AWS.

Also, I am unable to run the application locally using the command: `gradlew run -t classes`. The build is successful but the run command does not work as the endpoint in `postman` says `Could not get any response`.

I am unsure what the issue is. Any help is greatly appreciated.